# Datepicker issue when using cocoon Gem with Materialise Css and simple form in ruby on rails 5 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am using Cocoon gem for nested forms in my Rails app. I'm using it alongside materialize-form gem which allows me to use materialize css alongside simple form.

In the materialize-form gem notes it gives a solution to using nested form using the nested forms gem (Which only work in Rails 3). I am using cocooon gem instead. I am having this problem where "you have a date input in a nested field and you want to use jQuery datepicker for it. This is a bit tricky, because you have to activate datepicker after field was inserted."

The full description is under the Javascript events section here. https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

I believe the solution is to use this code.

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  window.materializeForm.init()
})
```

It listens for the nested:fieldAdded event from the nested_form gem code. Does anyone know how I can find the event I need to listen for when using the cocoon gem? In order to reload the materializeForm when I created a new nested field so it picks up the date picker.

I can set up an example app in heroku if need be and the example is not clear but it's basically not rerunning materialise form when a new nested field is added by cocoon gem.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Adding in my Html code >>>

// _form.html.erb file

```
   <h3>Dates</h3>
    <div id="schedules">
            <%= f.simple_fields_for :schedules do |schedule| %>
                <%= render 'schedule_fields', f: schedule %>
            <% end %>
            <div class="links">
                <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Schedule', f, :schedules %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

// _schedule_fields.html.erb file

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :event_schedule, label_html: { class: "active"}, wrapper_html: { class: 'col m12 s12 ' }, class: "datepicker" %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Schedule", f %>
</div>
```

*** Solution code to make nested field work with callback ***

```
$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', (function(event) {
    window.materializeForm.init() 
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the event that's called on the insertion/removal of items then the below may help. Take a look at the official Github repo for Cocoon (Search for Callbacks) for more info.
[https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon%20Cocoon%20Github%20Docs)

```
// A callback for cocoon so whenever a new association is made; the below will be executed.
$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', (function(event) {

}
```

Comment: Hmmm my javascript skills are awful. I was thinking this would work but this seems to do nothing.

$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', (function(event) {
 window.materializeForm.init()
}

Comment: I would try placing `console.log('Something Happened');` inside the callback to see if the event is being called.

Comment: I'm a donkey. So you were correct with the callback. I'd added this to my application.js file but never closed of the brackets properly. Seen the error when looking for the console log. I've been at this all day so was tired. Simple fix. Thanks @ThorTl67

"$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', (function(event) {
 window.materializeForm.init() 
}));"